# How to change theme in nuxt vuetify?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am new to nuxt and vue and I am trying to change color theme from dark to light. My project was generated by nuxt cli and I have got this versions:

```
"dependencies": {
"core-js": "^3.8.3",
"nuxt": "^2.14.12",
"vuetify": "^2.4.4"
}
"devDependencies": {
   "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3"
}
```

I am learning how to do this from this link: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/theme/

But actually when I am trying to change some colors or theme nothing happens. I was trying to pass light or dark props but still nothing happens

```
<v-app dark>...</v-app>
```

plugins/vuetify.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuetify from "vuetify/lib";

Vue.use(Vuetify);

export default new Vuetify({
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        primary: "#00bcd4",
        secondary: "#8bc34a",
        accent: "#3f51b5",
        error: "#e91e63",
        warning: "#ffeb3b",
        info: "#2196f3",
        success: "#4caf50"
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Did you tried to pass `light` in the `<v-app dark>...</v-app>` tag ? To replace `dark` by `light`. Or even just remove `dark` for the tag.

Comment: Yeah as I said in the question description, and I was trying also to remove this prop and still nothing happens, on app div I am getting 'theme--dark' class anyway

Comment: I think this is the fastest way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62005958/vuetify-toggle-between-light-and-dark-theme-with-vuex

Comment: @Freestyle09 Does everything from elements work or style is broken? Try remove /lib on importing Vuetify.

Comment: Everything works but only assigning new values to the theme is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created a nuxt project thanks to the CLI. The working project is hosted here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-dark-light-theme-iv8s4?file=/pages/index.vue

You need to make changes into the `vuetify.options.js` as recommended in the [official docs](https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module#optionspath).

To toggle the theme, you can use `this.$vuetify.theme.dark` as a setter, I've added some buttons. This info was taken from here: https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module/issues/213#issuecomment-551972535

Comment: Can you please help on how to change default colors as such let's say I want to have pink color in light mode or something like that

Comment: @ash this can probably be done by changing some CSS variables. Check the documentation for more details!

Comment: thankyou for the reply In the meanwhile I find out how they were getting used